# VS 2010: Select all controls inside container (tabpage,panel,...)

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, hotkeys

**Question:** How do i select all controls inside a container (tabpage in my case). Is there an menu option or Hotkey?

**Note:** I've tried `Ctrl + A` but its not working.

**Note2:** Selecting them all doesn't work (e.g. there are more controls that my screen can show)

Comment: There is no hotkey for this

Comment: Darn! Manual labor it is :) Thnx though